# How to test text with sikuli that has the same letters but different color in robot framework?

Tags: user-interface, robotframework, ui-automation, sikuli, robotframework-ide

When using robot frame work with Sikuli library the comparison of images is black and white based. 
How can the script fail if the text is correct but its color is wrong ?

Screen Should Contain    ${Stop_red_screenshot}

PS : the test pass even if stop is black

Here are two images :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Anything in particular you've already tried to overcome this?

Comment: i tried to compare the content of the text and it's color, even if the color is wrong my test = PASS

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the similarity to 0.99 or 1.0 [Set Minimum Similarity](http://rainmanwy.github.io/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/doc/SikuliLibrary.html#Set%20Min%20Similarity)?

Comment: No i didn't know about it

Comment: Get Match Score will give you the number itself.

Comment: What do you mean ? sorry i didn't understand you ?

Comment: Similarity and Match Score mean the same thing: a number from 0 to 1 highlighting the confidence that the matched image is indeed the source image. 1 being sure, 0 being unsure.

Comment: it's working ! thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by adding this line :

```
Set Min Similarity    0.99
```

before comparing images.

Thanks @A.Kootstra